# SpringComponentProvider.131 None or multiple beans found in Spring context for type class.. , skipping the type

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jersey, autowired

I have a application which is working fine without any error logs or issue.
On just adding a library in the pom (not even used in the code), i am started getting the below error message, but the application was working as expected.
Would like to understand what would case this error.

```
level=ERROR logger=server.spring.SpringComponentProvider.131  None or multiple beans found in Spring context for type class dummyclass, skipping the type.
```

Comment: which dependency add? add your spring-boot dependency also